# Exclude CSS, JS and IMG file from @WebServlet urlPattern Java

Tags: java, servlets, java-ee-8

My Servlet show product details by **slug**

```
@WebServlet("/*")
public class ProductDetails extends HttpServlet {
```

for example :

> mywebsite.com/product-name

But they can't load css, js and img files because it detect the pathInfo for a slug.

How can I exclude them to not be loaded in the servlet?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Servlet spec does not define exclusion rules for URL pattern mappings. Also, matched paths take precedence over matched suffixes (see Servlet 4 spec, paragraphs 12.1 & 12.2). The mapping on this Servlet will match anything in the application's context path, including static resources.

What can you do:

- You can split the logic to handle static resources in that servlet. I would not go for it, it will probably complicate the code and hurt the separation of concerns.
- If your static resources are inside a specific directory and no slug will match it (e.g. all JS, CSS, HTML, image files under `assets/`), you can have another Servlet that serves the static content under this directory (e.g. `@WebServlet("/assets/*")`). The longest path mapping that matches the request takes precedence. You still need to write code for sending a file back to the client; this code is fairly easy, you get a chance to customize the headers of the static files (e.g. caching), and, in comparison to the previous solution, the code that handles static files lies in it's own Servlet, so nice separation of concerns.
- If you do not want to bother with serving static files yourself (I wouldn't blame you), you can move the logic from your Servlet to another class. Then introduce a Servlet filter that will first check if the request is a GET for a static resource and, if so, simply calls `filterChain.doFilter(request,response)` and lets the application server handle the static file. If not, it calls your logic and sends the response that your Servlet would have sent.
- Finally, if you make your Servlet the default Servlet by `@WebServlet("/")` (not `"/*"`). It will pick up any request that other Servlets do not. The application server should have a Servlet installed for static content that will serve any existing CSS, JS, etc files from your application. Anything else will end up in your default Servlet.

If you could find a way to separate static content from dynamic content, e.g. all static content under `assets/`, all dynamic content under the virtual path `content/` it would be much easier to change the mapping of your Servlet to `/content/*` and be done with it.